# using QuaZip on Windows with VS2008

Tags: qt, quazip

I'm using QT4.7.3, VS2008 and trying to add QuaZip library.

I got QuaZip, Zlib and compile it, and then I can make "quazip.lib" file.

I added quazip.lib to "Project property->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies" and include pathes.

I wrote the source code as below.

```
#include "Updater.h"
#include "quazip.h"

Updater::Updater(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QuaZip *qZip = new QuaZip();
}
```

but, here, I stuck in problem.

Error message is shown as below.

> Updater.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: _*thiscall QuaZip::QuaZip(void)"
>   (*_imp_??0QuaZip@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall
>   Updater::Updater(class QWidget *,class QFlags)"
>   (??0Updater@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z)
>   1>.\updater.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I know this error occurs when declaration exists but definition doesn't exists.

As a result of find QuaZip constructor, I found as below.

```
QuaZip::QuaZip():
  p(new QuaZipPrivate(this))
{
}
```

How can I make it correct?

Thank you for any comment.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the following message in Quazip's README file:

> If you want to include QuaZIP sources directly into your project or if
>   you want to use QuaZIP compiled as a static library using
>   "qmake CONFIG+=statliclib", you have to define the QUAZIP_STATIC macro,
>   otherwise you're likely to run into problems as QuaZIP symbols will be
>   marked as dllimported.

Maybe that will help you.